# I get a "This site can’t be reached" after publishing my flask project by using Web deploy on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: python, visual-studio, flask, iis, publishing

So far I have tried to browse my website directly on IIS and get the error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/iis/http-error-500-19-webpage) I have an error in my web.config file, however, I have put the xml into a validator and it seems that there are no syntax errors.

Looking through a few questions I have made a hypothesis that the problem is occurring due to  targetFramework in my web.config. Please keep in mind that this is the first time I am publishing a website and do not yet entirely know the technicalities that one must be aware of to do so. As such I kindly request that you provide a solution that is elaborate enough so that I can easily apply it. Thanks in advance

This is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated web.config for Microsoft Azure. Remove this comment to prevent
     modifications being overwritten when publishing the project.
-->
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER" value="FlaskWebProject5.app" />
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_ACTIVATE_THIS" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot\flask_env_three\Scripts\python.exe" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.get_venv_handler()" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Python34\python.exe|D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="^/FlaskWebProject5/static/.*" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is desired, because IIS URL Rewrite module is not installed by default, and you need some manual steps.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your answer, I indeed did not have url rewrite installed. However after installing the x64 version, I am yet to see the url rewrite module on my iis manager.  Are there any additional steps I should be taking?

Comment: @LexLi Never mind, for some reason I had to restart iis twice to see it... Thanks again!

Comment: @LexLi Sorry to bother you again, I have stumbled onto a new issue. Now I am getting the error "<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration". Do you know what might be causing this? I have tried to resolve this issue before when I tried to publish my website directly from iis but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Tons of previous discussions are there. You need to configure Python FastCGI is two places (where you only did one of them). Using FastCGI to host Python on IIS is no longer the recommended approach compared to HttpPlatformHandler.